# Run script from different user

Tags: permissions, users

I have a script that download `db_dump` from production server.
I also created guest account so my friends that doesn't have permission to production, can get the downloaded files.

How can I give them permission to run the script as my user and only this script
so they don't have global `sudo` permission

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command with `su user -c "command"` where "user" is the name of the user and "command" is the actual command you wish to run. Be sure to put quotes (") around the command.

Comment: I need to give my user password in this way 
Is there away to avoid this for a specific script ?

Comment: Sorry, as far as I'm aware you will always need a password to issue commands from a user with a password. You could either set him up an account and add him to a group that has the appropriate permissions, or change the permissions for the specific script (`sudo chmod 777 script.py`) assuming this is safe and not going to be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make another Bash script in which will be command such as write **jessenorton** with password encrypted in SHA (or another) and this script file will have permission 710.

If you set 710 you can all (R,W,E), but friend can only execute script without reading pass in file, for sure encrypt that.

```
chmod 710 /path/to/file.sh
```

Or if you need executing it by anyone you must set 711, it is not best for secure, but it is more better and secure then 777 mentioned by **jessenorton** :-), in his case anyone can change code and it is high vulnerability.

It is possible solution for you?